# Prevent scrollable container within iframe from affecting site outside iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, xtermjs

I am working on a site that integrates a terminal into a website. The terminal is getting rendered using [xtermjs](https://xtermjs.org/) within an iframe. So the code finished html looks like this:

```html
<iframe src="http://localhost/term-shell/?course=nginx" class="display-under-terminal">
    <html data-lt-installed="true">

        <head>...</head>

        <body style="overflow: hidden;">
            <div id="console" class=" docker-browser-console">
                <!-- Everything from here on out gets generated by xterm -->
                <div dir="ltr" class="terminal xterm" tabindex="0">
                    <div class="xterm-viewport" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 1171px;">
                        <div class="xterm-scroll-area" style="height: 306px;"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="xterm-screen" style="width: 1161px; height: 119px;">
                        <div class="xterm-helpers"><textarea class="xterm-helper-textarea" aria-label="Terminal input"
                                aria-multiline="false" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false"
                                tabindex="0"
                                style="left: 0px; top: 102px; width: 9px; height: 17px; line-height: 17px; z-index: -5;"></textarea><span
                                class="xterm-char-measure-element" aria-hidden="true"
                                style="font-family: courier-new, courier, monospace; font-size: 15px;">W</span>
                            <div class="composition-view"></div>
                        </div><canvas class="xterm-text-layer" style="z-index: 0; width: 1161px; height: 119px;"
                            width="1161" height="119"></canvas><canvas class="xterm-selection-layer"
                            style="z-index: 1; width: 1161px; height: 119px;" width="1161" height="119"></canvas><canvas
                            class="xterm-link-layer" style="z-index: 2; width: 1161px; height: 119px;" width="1161"
                            height="119"></canvas><canvas class="xterm-cursor-layer"
                            style="z-index: 3; width: 1161px; height: 119px;" width="1161" height="119"></canvas>
                        <div class="xterm-decoration-container"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script src="bundle.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
</iframe>
```

The problem is that when I scroll within the terminal and reach the bottom or the top the parent page scrolls, which should be prevented.

I already tried setting the `overscroll-behavior` of `xterm-viewport` which is the scrollable container, but neither `none` or `contain` seem to work.

I also tried stopping propagation on the scroll event, but that didn't work either.